# Binary expansion

Tags: number-theory, binary, decimal-expansion

I am trying to get my head around the `left` and `right` shift for binary expansion. 
The rules are:

Shifting to the right corresponds to division by 2.

Shifting to the left corresponds to multiplication by 2.

This means if we have: 0.001100110011... = 1/5

If we shift this to the right we get 0.0001100110011... = 2/5 because 1/5÷2 = 2/5

If we shift this to the right we get 0.01100110011... = 1/10 because 1/5÷ 1/10

My question is, how do we get from  0.001100110011 to 1/5? ive tried binary expansion ie
0x2^-1 + 1x2^-2 + 1x2^-3 and so on...

But I get:

819/2048

This isnt 1/5.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is $0.\overline{0011}$.  The rule is that if you have a string of $n$ repeating symbols corresponding to the number $m$ in base $k$, then this repeating decimal corresponds to the fraction

$$\frac{m}{k^n - 1}$$

One way to see that this holds is that multiplication by $k^n$ would correspond to left shifting $n$ times.  In this case, we would get $11.\overline{0011}$.  Subtracting the original expression $0.\overline{0011}$ (before left shifting) gives us the number $m$.

So here, $n = 4$, $m = 3$, and $k = 2$, and the value of the decimal is

$$\frac{3}{16-1} = \frac{1}{5}$$